# Split a string and append it to a vector

Tags: r, string, split, append

I have a character vector where the string elements either have or don't have a slash(/).

`sem_tags <- ('F2', 'A1/B1', 'X3.2', 'M3fn', 'E2/Q2')`

I want those tags that have the slash to be stored as two separate tags so that in the end I get

`new_sem_tags <- ('F2', 'A1', 'B1', 'X3.2', 'M3fn', 'E2', 'Q2')`

Here is what I tried so far.

```
new_sem_tags <- c()
for (i in 1:length(sem_tags)){
  if (grepl("/", i)){
    append(new_sem_tags, str_split(i, '/'))
  } else {
    appendnew_sem_tags, i)
  }
  i = i+1
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. When I try every function separately, e.g., splitting and appending they seem to do the job. However, what I noticed is that appending returns the output but doesn't 'store' the output. Could that be the problem? If yes, how can I overcome it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In R, things are almost never stored/modified unless you assign the result with `<-` or `=`. If you start with `x <- 5`, `x+1` will print 6 but not change `x`--if you want to change `x` you need `x <- x + 1`. Similarly `append(x, 10)` will print `5  10`, but if you want to modify `x` you need `x <- append(x, 10)`. In your case, you could use `new_sem_tags <- append(new_sum_tags, ...)` (though lovalery's solution is cleaner).

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you for the comment! I tried it as well but it gave me a weird result. I got an integer vector `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... )` which reached to the length of the `sem_tags` vector.

Answer (score 6):

Using `base R`, you can do:

**Reprex**

```r
sem_tags <- c('F2', 'A1/B1', 'X3.2', 'M3fn', 'E2/Q2')

unlist(strsplit(sem_tags, "/"))
#> [1] "F2"   "A1"   "B1"   "X3.2" "M3fn" "E2"   "Q2"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks a lot! So simple and it worked!

Comment: @user22037 Thank you very much for your feedback. Glad that I could help. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

We can `scan` it in:

```
scan(text = sem_tags, what = "", sep = "/", quiet = TRUE)
## [1] "F2"   "A1"   "B1"   "X3.2" "M3fn" "E2"   "Q2"
```

### Note

The question has a syntax error in the definition of the input so we used this.

```
sem_tags <- c('F2', 'A1/B1', 'X3.2', 'M3fn', 'E2/Q2')
```